# How to keep fullcalendar popover shown when updating event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am working with FullCalendar in a web application and I am trying to make it dynamic as much as possible so the users won't have to reload the page to see the changes.

For the moment, I want to update an event color inside the popover without hiding it.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id='calendar'>

  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var events = [{
    id: 1,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    color: 'blue',
    title: 'Event 1',
  }, {
    id: 2,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    color: 'blue',
    title: 'Event 2',
  }, {
    id: 3,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    color: 'blue',
    title: 'Event 3',
  }, {
    id: 4,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    color: 'blue',
    title: 'Event 4',
  }, {
    id: 5,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    color: 'blue',
    title: 'Event 5',
  }, {
    id: 6,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(),
    color: 'blue',
    title: 'Event 6',
  }]

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next,today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: events

  });

  var events = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents');
  console.log(events)

  setTimeout(function() {
    var event = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
      return event.id == 6;
    });
    event[0].color = 'red';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event[0]);
    console.log(event);
  }, 5000);
</script>

</html>
```

I made a timeout function that will trigger a color update for the sixth event and that works but as you see the popup disappear after 5 sec and is there any way to keep it open when there's some event changes.

Comment: I spent a stupid amount of time looking into this. I'm afraid it's not possible, or at least, I can't figure it out. The library seems to depend on the popover being hidden before updating the color. You can see this for yourself if you edit fullcalendar.js source - comment out `this.segPopover.hide()` in the `DayGrid.mixin` block. You'll see your popover stays, but the color doesn't update until you dismiss the popover manually, and open it again. There's something in there about visibility determining `segPopover` being null. I would start there, but I'm out of my depth beyond there. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks you so much @Darren for spending time trying to resolve this issue, I really appreciate it a lot, As far as I understand, It's seems that the function `updateEvent` re-render the whole `fullcalendar` which makes resolving this issue impossible.

Comment: I haven't seen the source code but I would expect it would re-render all the events (if not the whole calendar) because the positioning of the other events could potentially be altered by the new position of the updated event. And if you changed the day the updated event occurs on, it might no longer even be necessary to have a popover. So for those reasons I'd expect the popover to be hidden, it's quite a logical thing to do. Unfortunately fullCalendar doesn't take into account that in reality you only changed the colour and not any of the times.